# Webkit inline position: absolute bug(?) at end of width

Tags: css, webkit, inline, css-position

Look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zVp4n/

*edited this one --> http://jsfiddle.net/zVp4n/1/

Look in Mozilla Firefox and then in any Webkit Browser (e.g. Google Chrome).
You will find out that it show different result.

I have 2 `<li>` there which share the exactly same styles. The first `<li>` has text which ends exactly at the end of width of the box (I think this is the BUG!!).
However I want webkit to show result as Mozilla does. Could anyone give me some fixes??

Comment: Why do you need `position: absolute` here? `display: inline-block` looks more like what you need: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/s9FS5/ (I also adjusted the amount of text)

Comment: No.. `display: inline-block` would make my `<span>` still in the **layout**. What I want here, it's not on the layout by change the `position:` into `relative`, `absolute`, or even `fixed`. And `position: absolute` is what fits my need here.

The problem, you could see the my fiddle attached above, try to open in Mozilla and webkit.. You will have different result. I want to fix it like Mozilla does.

Comment: ah sorry try this one.. http://jsfiddle.net/zVp4n/1/

Comment: It looks like some slight differences in width calculations and linewrap behavior.  If you enlarge the outer div a little bit, it becomes more obvious.  http://jsfiddle.net/zVp4n/6/

Comment: Yeah. That's the problem. Webkit, first of all, detect the end of the line when the end of text reaches the container's width. That causes my span appear on the next line..

Is there a fix for it? My website has dynamic text and expanding the width of the box is no solution here.. I want a fix that would do with any text-width

Is changing something about **wrap** will do any better??

Comment: This appears to be a similar bug report from a few years ago: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=18090. The pragmatic solution is to use JavaScript to do this instead. Otherwise, you can file your own bug report and wait.